# How to set wx.FileDialog window size?

Tags: python, wxpython, size

I have a small LCD screen and the open file dialog is too large.
Is there a way to specify a fixed size?

```
 dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, _("Open file to print"), basedir, style = wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST )
```

Regards
Giuseppe

Comment: It's a normal window... you can call `dlg.SetSize(wx.Size(sizew, sizeh))` to set its size. You could also try `dlg.Center()` to make it centered automatically. But to calculate its size, you'll need to also find the screen dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling the dialog's SetSize() method with a size tuple. However, this may not work if the default dialog does not support resizing. For example, on Windows, I was not able to reduce the size of the dialog on creation by very much. Here's some code for you to play with though:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Dialogs")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Open Dialog")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.openFileDlg)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def openFileDlg(self, event):
        """"""
        wildcard = "Python source (*.py)|*.py|" \
            "All files (*.*)|*.*"


        dlg = wx.FileDialog(
            None, message="Choose a file",
            defaultDir="/", 
            defaultFile="",
            wildcard=wildcard,
            style=wx.OPEN | wx.MULTIPLE | wx.CHANGE_DIR
            )
        dlg.SetSize((100,100))

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            paths = dlg.GetPaths()
            print "You chose the following file(s):"
            for path in paths:
                print path
                dlg.Destroy()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I am working under X11 and it seems that the dialogue is not resizable, my LCD is a 7-inch and my main app is correctly displayed in 1280x720.
However, I partially solved the problem by changing the style of the dialog box, in the sense that the non-visible part is decreased.
Thank you very much for the support
regards